# How to sent few Bytes on android via bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, hex

I have a problem with sending bytes via Bluetooth on Android.
I got this code from Stackoverflow:

```
private boolean connected = false;
private BluetoothSocket sock;
private InputStream in;
private OutputStream out;

zee = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(
        "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX");
    m = zee.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
        new Class[] { int.class });
    sock = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(zee, Integer.valueOf(1));
    sock.connect();
    in = sock.getInputStream();
    out = sock.getOutputStream();

char[] test = { 0x55, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x50, 0x2, 0x0,
        0x30, 0xD7 };

for(int k=0; k < test.lenght; k++){
new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream()).writeByte(test[k]);
}




for(int k=0; k < test.lenght; k++){
new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream()).writeByte(test[k]);
}
```

Bytes goes one by one... but i need to send them in one packet. What method i need to use? How to do this?

Comment: leng**th** not leng**ht**

Comment: Thank you \0/ (confused)

Comment: Bytes goes one by one... but i need to send them in one pack. What method i need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me:

```
OutputStream outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
byte[] test = {0x03, 0x40, 0x00, (byte) ch2, (byte) 0xC1, (byte) 0xC0};
outStream.write(test);
```